# Python Dictionary as Variable?

Tags: python-3.x

Define the `draw_histogram()` function which is passed a Python dictionary as a parameter.  The keys of the dictionary are single letters and the corresponding values are integers, e.g., `{'b': 5, 'a': 6, 'c': 3}`.    For each key:value pair in the dictionary the function prints the key, followed by "`:` ", followed by a series of stars.  The number of stars printed is given by the value corresponding to the key.  The keys are printed in alphabetical order.  For example, the following code:

```
draw_histogram({'c':3, 'a':6, 'b':5})
```

prints the following three lines:

```
a: ******

b: *****

c: ***
```

I am so confused as to what the question is actually asking me to do, so I am not sure how to even start the answer to the question. Please advice.

Comment: It's asking you to define a function called draw_histogram that takes a python dictionary as a parameter. It's further telling you that the output of that function should be to print each key value pair as the actual key, and then the same number of asterisks as the number defined in the value. they don't specify but I assume you would want to handle dictionaries that have non-numeric values.

Comment: I don't really know how to have python dictionary as a parameter - as we haven't been taught that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have a Python dictionary as a parameter just like you would have anything else as a parameter. You can give it a name and call it whatever you like, i.e. `def draw_histogram(numbers):`. In Python you don't have to specify the data type being passed through, so it will read the dictionary and store it as `numbers` in this case. Then you create a loop that iterates through every value in your dictionary. Have it print the key (a, b, or c), and then the stars times the value. So you might have something that looks like `stars = "*" * numbers[key]` to print your stars depending on what you call your variables, where stars would be "*****"  at b. I won't give too much code since it is a homework assignment, but if you need further help, please let me know!

Comment: So it's basically the same as passing it any other parameter? So I just need to make a for loop that goes through the key, something like "for key in dictionary:". Would it help if I converted it to a tuple, so 'a':6 will be a tuple and then 'b':5 will be another?

Comment: That is exactly correct! Are you familiar with referencing dictionaries and accessing keys?

Comment: No I don't know how to reference a dictionary and access the keys. It's probably why I don't really understand the question.

Comment: This has a few good examples: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html . However, in your case, you just want to access each key regardless of what it's called, so the most efficient way to do the is to say `for key in numbers: ` (remember I'm calling the dictionary "numbers" and then Python will automatically assign "key" the the value of the key, which you can work with. Then you can access the value by saying numbers[key].

Comment: Actually I'm looking at the problem, and that last comment was probably overkill and too complicated for what you're trying to do. Hang on.

Comment: Instead what you want to do is get the number of stars by saying `stars = "*" * numbers['a']` and that will yield '******'. Then if you print out 'a; ', and stars, that will give you the first line. Do that for all three, and you'll be set!

Comment: I understand that, I think. But to get the numbers I have to access the letter and then the number assigned to it right? So my code should go through the key and see what letter it is and then check the number assigned to it and then print the letter and then the stars * number? How do I access the dictionary key to see what letter is being passed with what key - that's what I am confused about

Comment: Actually I think I should be able to do it using the for key in numbers method.

Comment: So, this is a bit of a special case where you know all of the names of your keys. So instead of having Python loop through and see what the key is, you can just know that there is a key 'a'. Then to access the value associated with a you say numbers['a']. It would be better programming to make a loop, but this is a very simple assignment and that would take a long time to explain.

Comment: I was able to get it working by using: for key in numbers: and then specifying stars = "*" * numbers [key] and then printing key ": " stars

Comment: I am having one issue though. The answer is coming out as a, c, b - they key is being randomised when it prints - the code requires it to be a and then b and then c - regardless of the order the dictionary has it

Comment: Managed to fix it - ran the keys through a list, sorted the list, ran the for function for the list feeding it back to the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.x your function could be

```
def draw_histogram(dct):
    [print(key, ':', '*' * dct[key]) for key in sorted(dct)]
```

It takes the dictionary as its only argument and prints the sorted 'a', 'b', 'c' keys and the number of asterisks associated with each key in the dictionary. So...

```
draw_histogram({'c':3, 'a':6, 'b':5})
```

results in...

a : ****** 
b : ***** 
c : ***

Comment: Creating list of `None` values just to trigger side-effect if weird. It'll be much less confusing with explicit loop statement.

Comment: @Rogalski I don't think there's a large difference in how a beginner would intuit `[print(key, ':', '*' * dct[key]) for key in sorted(dct)]` vs. `for key in sorted(dct): print (key, ':', '*' * dct[key])`